# Is it possible to interpolate across a time series with influence from other columns?

Tags: python-3.x, interpolation

I have a dataframe that contains missing data. I'm interested in exploring interpolation as a possible alternative to removing columns with missing data.

Below is a subset of the dataset. 'a_out' is outdoor temperature while 'b_in' etc. are temperatures from rooms in the same house.

```
              a_out   b_in    c_in   d_in    e_in    f_in
...           ...     ...     ...    ...     ...     ...
03/01/2016    6.51    17.71   15.15  14.04   15.27   16.32
04/01/2016    5.94    17.49   14.34          14.71   
05/01/2016    6.74    17.57   14.80          15.18   
06/01/2016    5.86    17.49   14.68  18.43   15.57   
07/01/2016    5.18    17.18   14.02          14.88   
08/01/2016    2.84    16.80   13.15          14.51   14.48
...           ...     ...     ...    ...     ...     ...
```

Might there be a way to interpolate the missing data, but with some weighting based on intact data in other columns? Perhaps 'cubic' interpolation could do the trick?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don’t you try it and find out?

Comment: I have been :) I was hoping that one of the wise people here might know the vocabulary that I might be missing.

Comment: And what were the results of your attempts?

Comment: I'll re-write the question to include - thanks for your help @mkrieger1